# How do I check if a string is included in an array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my **PostgreSQL** database (`version: 11.4`) I have a table called `table_1` which has only one column. The data type of this column is string array (`_varchar`).

```
| dependencies   |
|----------------|
|{\1}            | 
|{\1,\1\2}       |
|{\1,\1\2,\1\2\3}|
```

Also, I have a table called `table_2` which has such structure:

```
| employee       | dependence |
|----------------|------------|
| Alex           | \1         |
| Mark           | \1         |
| Lily           | \1\2       |
| Grace          | \1\2       |
| Evie           | \1\2       |
| Bob            | \1\2\3     |
| Mark           | \1\2       |
```

How do I check if a string is included in an array? In my case, I tried to check if the `dependence` column value from `table_2` exists in arrays of the `dependencies` column of `table_1`.

In other words, I'm trying to get a such result:

```
| dependencies   | total |
|----------------|-------|
|{\1}            | 2     | 
|{\1,\1\2}       | 6     |
|{\1,\1\2,\1\2\3}| 7     |
```

SQL request which I tried:

```
select
    table_1.dependencies,
    calculation.total
from
    table_1
join lateral (
    select
        count(*) as total
    from
        table_2
    where
        table_2.dependence in table_1.dependencies /* ? */
) calculation on 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this with field `TEXT[]`

```
select dependencies ,count(*) from table_1 join table_2
on dependence  = ANY( dependencies)
group by 1
```

**table_1**

```
create table table_1
(
    dependencies text[]
);
insert into public.table_1 (dependencies) values ('{1}');
insert into public.table_1 (dependencies) values ('{1,12}');
insert into public.table_1 (dependencies) values ('{1,12,123}');
```

**table_2**

```
create table if not exists table_2
    (
        employee varchar,
        dependence text
    );
insert into public.table_2 (employee, dependence) values ('Mark', 12);
insert into public.table_2 (employee, dependence) values ('Lily', 12);
insert into public.table_2 (employee, dependence) values ('Evie', 12);
insert into public.table_2 (employee, dependence) values ('Alex', 1);
insert into public.table_2 (employee, dependence) values ('Mark', 1);
insert into public.table_2 (employee, dependence) values ('Grace', 12);
insert into public.table_2 (employee, dependence) values ('Bob', 123);
```